# Update HP Proliant Gen 10 Firmware Running VMWare esxi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, firmware-update

I've got a HP Proliant Gen 10 Microserver running VMWare ESXi 6.5. I haven't updated the firmware since I've had it but recently begun having problems with overheating. I found articles saying the firmware update should solve this.

Originally I was trying to update the firmware in online mode, after struggling with the instructions from the HP Gen 10 Service Pack for Proliant, I rang technical support who advised me to do the update in offline mode using a bootable USB. I tried creating a bootable USB using Rufus, this produced some errors when I tried to run it so I found I had to use usbkey.exe found in the service pack ISO file. This worked better as it actually booted and ran in automatic update mode.

The update got to 97% saying "Mounting root file system image please wait.." and got stuck. I left it running overnight and it was still on 97%. I stopped it and retried it and had the same problem.

After some research I found I may have to update the RAID Controller, I did this using HPE ProLiant Gen 10 Smart Array Controller Driver for VMWare vSphere 6.5 (VIB file) and retried the firmware update from the service pack. Again it got to 97% and got stuck.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted file. You should redownload everything.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried a couple of new Service Pack downloads yesterday. Today I tried again starting from the beginning on a different laptop and using a different USB and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a solution. I contacted technical support and was told that the Service Pack for Proliant didn't support the HP Proliant Gen10 Microserver, only the Gen10 Plus Microserver. As such I was directed to "System Firmware Upgrade for HPE MicroServer Gen10 Server with UEFI".

Something userful to note is that inside the Built-in UFEI shell "map -r" lists the available devices and makes finding the inserted USB easier.